# Bazel linking .dll for SDL2 project

Tags: dll, linker, linker-errors, bazel, sdl-2

I was wondering how to properly set up the Bazel target for SDL2 with the Windows dynamic and static libraries. What can I change in my `BUILD` file to account for the `.dll` files for the Windows SDL2 library?

Here is my Git repository for reference. (specifically `third_party/BUILD` and `main/BUILD`)

https://github.com/desmondcchi/bullet_hell_sdl2_game

When I run the binary `//main:bullet_hell_main`, this is the error that shows up:

```
ERROR: D:/dev/bullet_hell_sdl2_game/main/BUILD:3:10: Linking main/bullet_hell_main.exe failed: (Exit 1181): link.exe failed: error executing command (from target //main:bullet_hell_main) C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe @bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/main/bullet_hell_main.exe-2.params
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/framework'; ignored
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'OpenGL.obj'
Target //main:bullet_hell_main failed to build
```

However, other targets that have the SDL2 target as a dependency build fine (such as `//game:game`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I have tried copying the SDL2.dll files (inside `third_party/sdl2/2.28.2/windows_x64/bin`) into the `bazel-bin` folder and that does not seem to work. As you can see in `third_party/BUILD` I set up the SDL2 target so that it switches dependencies when I develop on macOS and Windows.

Comment: https://github.com/bazelregistry/sdl2